# Code popup has ridiculously small font on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, code-block

The code popup that appears when tapping inside a code block sometimes has a ridiculously small font. For example: [an answer on PPCG.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42468/25183).

[image: screenshot]

<sup>(Click the image for full-size)</sup>

Nexus 5, Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop), Stack Exchange app 1.0.51.

Comment: I've noticed this before the most recent app update. (maybe since upgrading my Nexus 5 to lollipop, but sure).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yeah, I think I'm also getting this since I upgraded to Lollipop. I don't remember using older versions of the app on Lollipop.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, app v1.0.82 (beta). Could you try it again with the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: long code will be shown on normal font size with scrollable code block popup, instead of trying to fit the code on the popup.

[image: normal font size on code popup]